# problem during initiation of a module in another module

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

i'm getting an error in the exp function instantiation in the activation module. I'm not able to understand the error in the code. have i done a mistake with respect to the instantiation?

please help me find out!

code -

```
module exp (input [15:0] g, output [15:0] f);
real base = 2.71828;
assign f = $realtobits(base ** g) ;
endmodule

module activation(input method,
input ctrl,
input [15:0] imgin[127:0],
output reg [15:0] imgo[127:0]
);

`define ONE 16'h0100;

reg [15:0] y; 

integer i;
always@(ctrl)
for(i=0; i<128 ; i=i+1)
begin 

if(method == 1'b0)   begin  // for relu unit 
if (imgin[i][15])
imgo[i] = 16'h0000;

else if(imgin[i] > 16'b0)
imgo[i]= imgin[i];

else if(imgin[i]>16'b1)
imgo[i]=16'd1;

end

if(method == 1'b1)   begin  // for sigmoid function
  exp f1(.g(imgin[i]),.f(y));   // error here
  imgo[i] = 1/(1+ y);

end
end


endmodule
```

Comment: module cannot be `instantiated` inside always blocks. This is exactly what you have: `exp` is instantiated there.

Comment: Be aware that even after resolving the instantiation problem, `1/(1+ y)` will always evaluate to 0 because it is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Initially I tried to answer the question by also giving solution with uses a module and only suggested to use a function. However, as Greg pointed out in a comment to this answer, a function is the way to go. Therefore, I removed the attempt to answer this question by using a module.

---

What you are trying to do is to instantiate a module under a certain condition. This is not possible the way you are trying to do this. As described in section 27 of the [IEEE Std 1800-2012.](http://www.ece.uah.edu/~gaede/cpe526/2012%20System%20Verilog%20Language%20Reference%20Manual.pdf) ("the Verilog manual"), you can use `generate` constructs to conditionally instantiate modules. This looks generally like this:

```
generate
  if (SOME_CONDITION)
     // Instantiate a module
  else
     // Instantiate another module or do nothing
endgenerate
```

However, in your case, this is not necessary. Instead, you should use a function for this. Section 13.4 of the aforementioned manual points out how to use functions and also [this tutorial of nandland.com](https://www.nandland.com/verilog/examples/example-function-verilog.html). You can condintionally call functions. Basically, your code would look like this with a function:

```
module activation(input             method,
                  input             ctrl,
                  input      [15:0] imgin   [127:0],
                  output reg [15:0] imgo    [127:0]);

  function exp;
    input [15:0] g;
    real         base;

    begin
      base = 2.71828;
      exp  = $realtobits(base ** g);
    end
  endfunction

  `define ONE 16'h0100;

  reg [15:0] y;

  integer i;
  always@(ctrl)
    for(i=0; i<128 ; i=i+1)
    begin

    if(method == 1'b0)   begin  // for relu unit 
      if (imgin[i][15])
        imgo[i] = 16'h0000;
      else if(imgin[i] > 16'b0)
        imgo[i]= imgin[i];
      else if(imgin[i]>16'b1)
        imgo[i]=16'd1;
    end
    else if (method == 1'b1) begin  // for sigmoid function
       y = exp(imgin[i]);
       imgo[i] = 1/(1+ y);
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to define a function at root. It should be defined inside the module or a SystemVerilog package. Also, simple moving the the `f1` instance outside the always block will not work because of the for-loop. The instance will only see final version of `imgin_temp` and the always block will only see the previous value of `y`. Function is the way to go.

Comment: @Greg thanks for your feedback. You are absolutely right. I removed the attempt to answer this question by using a module and also moved the function to the right position in the code.